PyCharm is not suggesting packages upgrades on requirements.txt
I use requirements.txt to manage packages in my Python project.
Before, when I opened requirements.txt, PyCharm used to highlight all packages that have new versions available, with a Quick Fix button that allow to upgrade the package and updates requirements.txt.
Today PyCharm only highlights packages that are not installed or that have security issues, but don't even suggest a version upgrade.
I checked all inspections and can't find anything related.
Some entries in my requirements.txt:
pytest==8.1.1   # current version 8.2.2
pymongo==4.6.3  # current version 4.7.3
pylint==3.1.0   # current version 3.2.3

If I change a version on requirements.txt and open a .py file, it shows a message that "Package pytest-8.1.1 is not satisfied" with a button "Install requirement".
In Python Packages it show new versions, and I can click on the version to update, but after the update, it will show the message that "Package pytest-old-version is not satisfied" and the button "Install requirement" will install the old version, unless I manually change in requirements.txt.

Don't suppose it's a PyCharm Professional feature?

This has been driving me crazy. I can't figure out how to update packages as quickly as I used to.

I started using pip-check-updates: pip install pip-check-updates; run pcu on command line, get the list of available updates.
